# Package path of "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" permission for Advertising Id

Tags: android, ads, google-mobile-ads, google-advertising-id

I am not able to find below permission in Manifest.Permission package [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

> "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"

Can anyone help me out where can I find this `AD_ID` permission, I want to know its package/path, probably it will be in Google Mobile Ads package, but not able to find it.